# MongoDB Select MIN/MAX from values inside Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm having issues performing a Query to return just two values, MIN and MAX for a field inside an Array field...

`client.files.uploads` is the field I want to get the MIN/MAX.

The result will be just "`0,10`" for example, I don't want to get more fields, just look into every `client.files.uploads` field and get the MIN/MAX uploads whole `client`collection has, but return **only the lowest and highest value** not a row for each client.

This is my query, but is not getting me what I want...

```
db.client.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$files"},
    { 
        $group: { 
            _id : "$_id",
            data_min: {$min: "$files.uploads"},
            data_max: {$max: "$files.uploads"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            data_min: "$min",
            data_max: "$max",
        }
    }
],{allowDiskUse:true})
```

UPDATE:

I've managed to do what I wanted, but the question still open because I don't thing my way is the best way to achieve it...

```
db.clients.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$files"},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      data_min: {$min: "$files.uploads"},
      data_max: {$max: "$files.uploads"}
    }
  },
  {

    $group: {
      _id: "1",
      min: {$min: "$data_min"},
      max: {$max: "$data_max"}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      min: 1,
      max: 1
    }
  }
],
{
  allowDiskUse: true
})
```

This query is returning me one row only, with the lowest and highest value for the whole collection, which is what I wanted.

This is an example data of my documents

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "files": [
      {
        "uploads": 9685,
        "downloads": 83,

      },
      {
        "uploads": 1,
        "downloads": 833
      },
      {
        "uploads": 676,
        "downloads": 823
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Peter",
    "files": [
      {
        "uploads": 32,
        "downloads": 99
      },
      {
        "uploads": 34,
        "downloads": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Mery",
    "files": [
      {
        "uploads": 3,
        "downloads": 244
      },
      {
        "uploads": 15,
        "downloads": 543
      },
      {
        "uploads": 1345,
        "downloads": 22
      },
      {
        "uploads": 6743,
        "downloads": 87543
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your projection is wrong. You are using [*accumulator operator*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#aggregation-accumulator-operators) as values. Change your projection to this:

```
{
    $project:{
        _id: 0,
        data_min: 1,
        data_max: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but I've changed my question as it seemed to be wrong, i not only want to get thoose two fields only (which is your answer and is 100% correct) i meant I wanted to return only ONE row, with the lowest and highest values for the whole collection, something that I've accomplished with two groups, but Maybe there are better options (see my update)

Comment: your aggregation is good but in your second `$group` use  `_id: null` instead of  `_id: "1"`

Comment: Okay, thank you, I've changed it. I thought that maybe my query was not good (even if it works) because of the two groups, and maybe there were another way to achieve it.. Thank you

Comment: Yeah sorry I was away and totally forgot about stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Check this aggregation query

```
db.clients.aggregate({"$unwind": "$files"},
                     {"$project":{"name":"$name","files":"$files"}},
                     {"$group":{"_id":"$_id","max":{"$max":"$files"},
                                             "min":{"$min":"$files"}}
                     }).pretty()
```

Or use `$project` as below

```
db.clients.aggregate({"$unwind": "$files"},
                     {"$project":{"name":"$name","files":"$files"}},
                     {"$group":{"_id":"$_id","max":{"$max":"$files"},
                                              "min":{"$min":"$files"}}},
                     {"$project":{"max_upload":"$max.uploads",
                     "max_download":"$max.downloads",
                     "min_upload":"$min.uploads",
                     "min_downloads":"$min.downloads","_id":0
                                  }
                     })
```

Comment: It will not work. Just tested. Also what is wrong with OP query?